# Subtracting Time for a given user based on allowed Time and multiple entries

Tags: google-sheets

I have data coming from a form into a response sheet. This data represents information from a therapy session. It includes the date, time (units), individual id, individual name, etc. Each individual is allotted a certain amount of time which is located in the AllClients sheet (column C). I need help creating a formula that will look at all the data in the Form Responses sheet, specifically the units per session (Column K) for each user, and then subtract it from the allotted time given for each client (Column C). Total units left for each client will be (Column D)

Here is the sheet I am working on.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8UVfpkyeba1WD-r8X82qlMA3cCR-_VlSFisHEy3lFY/edit#gid=334495985

Answer (score 0):

Enter this calculation in cell D2 of the "AllClients" sheet

```
=arrayformula( if ( A2:A<>"", C2:C - sumif('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, A2:A,'Form Responses 1'!K2:K), ""))
```

The result will be:
[image: result]